# How Do I Count When Numbers Do Not Show Up

Tags: vb.net

I have numbers from 1 to 25, four numbers will show up daily. I need to put a +1 on each of the four numbers and need to put a -1 on each of the 21 numbers didn't show up.

The four numbers that come up daily will be inputted in four different text boxes. The count being positive or negative needs to go on 25 separate text boxes labeled 1 thru 25.

I have tried "if textbox <> number, then count -= 1" but I get a count of -4 because it doesn't see the number in any of the four text boxes.

I only need a daily count not a textbox count. Sorry I don't have any code started and would greatly appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. I'm doing this on Visual Studio 2012.

Thank you all for responding. Here is some code I've started but the count is not correct. My four input text boxes are in GroupBox2. Four numbers from 1 to 25 will draw daily like a lottery. The four numbers drawn will have a value of +1 each all others -1. I need to find the age of each number 1 thru 25. If a number has a +3 then that means that number has drawn 3 consecutive days. If a number has a -15 then that means that number has not drawn for the past 15 days.

```
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim Counter As Integer
    For Each ctrl In GroupBox2.Controls
        tb = ctrl
        If tb.Text = 1 Then
            Counter += 1
        ElseIf tb.Text <> 1 Then
            Counter -= 1
            TextBox464.Text = Counter
        End If
        If tb.Text = 2 Then
            Counter += 1
        ElseIf tb.Text <> 2 Then
            Counter -= 1
            TextBox463.Text = Counter
        End If
        If tb.Text = 3 Then
            Counter += 1
        ElseIf tb.Text <> 3 Then
            Counter -= 1
            TextBox462.Text = Counter
        End If
        If tb.Text = 4 Then
            Counter += 1
        ElseIf tb.Text <> 4 Then
            Counter -= 1
            TextBox461.Text = Counter
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're going to have to [edit] and clarify your question (and ideally format it a little too, so it doesn't read like a plain wall of text) - please see [ask].

Comment: Code and screenshots help explain what you want, try to add some. `count numbers that show up` where ?

Comment: `if textbox <> number`  A TextBox is a control, not a number.  The Text property of the TextBox holds a string.  You are probably better off using a NumericUpDown control for your display.  Use the Value property to get or set the number.  Otherwise, you would have to use Integer.TryParse to convert your text into numbers.  No one here knows what you mean by "numbers will show up daily".

Comment: Add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code file _or_ set it in your projects properties.  You are trying to compare the `Text` property of your text boxes which is a string with an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

We will need more information about how your going to approach it to be able to help you further, but as for your problem with this `If Textbox <> number Then count -= 1` you can use something like this since your only going to be having numbers on the textboxes `If Cint(Textbox.Text) <> number then count -= 1` since your using just `Textbox` its attempting to evaluate it as a control and not the property that your looking for, you need to read from its `.Text` Property, However since its evaluated as a String and not an Integer it will throw an error exception, thats why the `Cint()`  is included (This may also be used to convert it to integer `Ctype(number, Integer)` Not sure if there is an execution speed difference or not, however `Cint()` is a faster way of writing it.) it will try and convert the String into an Integer and when its converted into an integer it can be evaluated like one using `<>`. No one is going to write a whole solution out for you, but while you attempt to create it yourself and more information can be added we are more than happy to help you with problems along the way.